# I'm trying to deploy a Secret Network NFT with a deploy script, but secret.js does not appear to have Secp256k1Pen?

Tags: webassembly, nft, rust-wasm

I am building a Secret NFT and I'm following this tutorial https://youtu.be/jRuSOos9ig4. I tried to deploy the NFT like this video narrator does around 31:12. I ran a the deploy-nft.js file that failed at this line:

```
const signingPen = await Secp256k1Pen.fromMnemonic(mnemonic).catch((err) => {
  throw new Error(`Could not get signing pen: ${err}`);
});
```

With this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromMnemonic')
    at main (C:\Users\nyusername\path\to\secret-nft-two\contract\deploy-nft.js:40:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nyusername\path\to\secret-nft-two\contract\deploy-nft.js:94:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I imported Secp256k1Pen at the top of the file like this:

```
const {
  EnigmaUtils,
  Secp256k1Pen,
  SigningCosmWasmClient,
  pubkeyToAddress,
  encodeSecp256k1Pubkey,
} = require("secretjs");
```

So why is it failing with this error?

Comment: can you pls create a reproducible repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secret.js https://secretjs.scrt.network/ appears to have removed Secp256k1Pen as one of its exports.

Instead you create the client object that's capable of signing like this:

```
const wallet = new Wallet(process.env.MNEMONIC);

const secretjs = new SecretNetworkClient({
  url: process.env.SECRET_REST_URL,
  wallet: wallet,
  walletAddress: wallet.address,
  chainId: process.env.VITE_SECRET_CHAIN_ID,
});
```

And you sign a transaction like this (this is a contract upload transaction):

```
const wasm = fs.readFileSync('my-snip721/contract.wasm.gz');
console.log('Uploading contract');

const tx = await secretjs.tx.compute.storeCode(
  {
    sender: wallet.address,
    wasm_byte_code: wasm,
    source: "https://github.com/baedrik/snip721-reference-impl",
    builder: "",
  },
  {
    gasLimit: 4_000_000,
  }
);
```